# Problems building a closure-compiler/typescript front end workflow

Tags: typescript, npm, gulp, browserify, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying to build a useful workflow using `gulp`, `closure-compiler` and `typescript` using npm modules hosted from a private sinopia repository.

The end goal is the following:

- To develop with browserify and typescript, and publish shared code to the private npm repository.
- To subsequently optimize a web application project using closure compiler.

(Closure compiler is not optional, UglifyJS does not perform the level of optimizations I want in terms of file size and performance)

This is all working perfectly when my project is entirely self contained in my source tree (i.e. I haven't `npm install`ed any modules.  Here is the working gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var size = require('gulp-size');
var server = require('gulp-live-server');
var typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
var closureCompiler = require('gulp-closure-compiler');

/** No minification */
gulp.task('compile-dev', function() {
    console.log("compile-dev at "+new Date())
    var b = browserify({baseDir: "src", debug: true})
        .add("src/main.ts")
        .plugin('tsify', { noImplicitAny: true, target: "es6"});
    b.bundle()
    .on('error', function(error) {
        console.error(error.toString());
    })
    .pipe(source("out.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("www"))
})

/* minify with closure */
gulp.task('compile-closure', function () {
    gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(typescript({target: "es6"}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build"))
    .pipe(closureCompiler({
        fileName: "out.js",
        compilerFlags: {
            language_in: "ES6",
            language_out: "ES5",
            compilation_level: "ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS"
        }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("www"))
    .pipe(size({gzip: true, showFiles: true }))
});
```

Now I run into three interrelated problems using modules:

- publishing the npm package and compiling the toplevel project with typescript's `target: "es6"` causes browserify in the `compile-dev` task to choke with `ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`.  If I compile the module with typescript `target: "es5"`, we're back and working for `compile-dev`, so actually in that sense- `compile-dev` is working perfectly, assuming I target "es5" everywhere.
- moving down to "es5", causes closure compiler to choke with `Error: build/main.js:2: WARNING - dangerous use of the global this object
  var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {` - closure doesn't like to consume the es5 that typescript produces
- if I stick with "es6" for the typescript target, not only does browserify choke on `compile-dev`, but closure also (perhaps understandably) still can't find my library because it does not know to look in node_modules if I `import Foo from "bar"`.

So how can I:

- get closure-compiler to look in node_modules when I require from an external library (without a ./)?
- allow browserify to consume these es6 modules in npm?

Comment: I'm working on support for closure-compiler to be able to lookup `node_modules` dependencies. It's not an option yet though.

Comment: You should be able to define the es6 module roots so the Closure Compiler can find the module.

Comment: @John how might I go about doing that? From the doc, it seems that "paths must be absolute or relative", so it doesn't seem to me that closure could find the module named `"foo"`- rather it would have to be imported as `"./foo"`

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth this is an absolute killer feature! Is there a public fork that contains a work in progress? I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @mseddon There is not yet public work to reference for this. There are core changes in the compiler that need made.

Comment: I believe John is referring to the `--js_module_root` flag.

Comment: @MatrixFrog thanks- I can't find the documentation for it, but looking at examples I am not certain I can get it to work since I don't think I can alias names (e.g. a lot of npm modules use index.js as their name- wouldn't I then only be able to import "index" to access these?), also I am worried what would happen if two modules had a private module named "foo.js"- would closure be smart enough to provide the correct file in each case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet possible with closure compiler as the compiler does not know how to lookup named modules. The only option would be to use a bundler which can eliminate named module references prior to compilation.